# How to Move JLabes Around

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


        public class Gui_Window extends JFrame {
            private JLabel Main_L;

            public Gui_Window() {
                setLayout(new FlowLayout());

                Main_L = new JLabel("Did you know it is possible to bind keys?");
                add(Main_L);
            }

                public static void main (String args[]) {
                    Gui_Window gui = new Gui_Window();
                    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    gui.setSize(300,300);
                    gui.setVisible(true);
                    gui.setTitle("Gamers AudioMute");
                    gui.setResizable(true);


            }
        }
```

I would like to know how to move my "Did you know" Label around. Could you also state how to align left, right, middle and how to move it around by its coordinates?

[image: IMG of the Program]

Comment: You should read [Lesson: Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Comment: You should also read [Using toplevel Swing containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) to learn things like avoiding extending `JFrame` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use methods included in Swing classes. Try

```
mainL.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
mainL.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
```

The two methods `setHorizontalAligment` and `setVeritcalAlignment` both take integers that will set the start of either the horizontal or vertical component of the label to that pixel integer within the Swing window.

You should also read up on SwingConstants which allow you to plug in pre-defined integers by Swing that will align your texts to desirable locations within the panel. Here's a link

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingConstants.html

They are also useful when manipulating different layouts such as `BorderLayout` and `GridLayout`.

Comment: That's a nice idea, but will only work if the JLabel is larger then text it needs to contain